# ADB Locked Android Device Unauthorized

Tags: android, adb

My device Mi A3 is broken (screen not working). I want to unlock it but unable to put in the pin as my screen is not working.

I have read through multiple answers regarding this and have tried everything but up to no avail. I am using the **adb** to unlock my phone but the main problem is that after typing `adb devices` it shows that my device is "unauthorized". After searching on the internet I got to know that there are couple of ways to resolve this problem: one of them is to go to developer settings on the phone and "revoke USB debugging authorization", another one is to delete the adbkey and then on the next connection the phone will be prompted to allow for permission. But I cannot do any of these as my screen is not working.

Any ideas how I can resolve this "unauthorized" issue without unlocking my phone?
P.S.: I don't want to factory reset my phone.

Comment: "Any ideas how I can resolve this "unauthorized" issue without unlocking my phone?" -- that is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Connect a simple USB keyboard and enter the PIN.